# Get All Unique Values in a Row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame `df1` that looks like this:

```
A       B       C
-----------------
1       1       2
2       2       3
5       4       9
```

I want to get all the unique values in a row. For example 1 and 2 in the first row. 2, 3 in the second row. And 4, 5 and 9 in the third row.

Result can vary, I can imagine a new column that contains a list with unique values or replacing duplicates with `None` would be also okay (or something else, maybe there is something more pythonic for this case).

Comment: What format do you want your output? There's a `numpy` function `numpy.unique()` that you can apply to all rows.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
list(map(set,df.values))
Out[72]: [{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {4, 5, 9}]
```

Comment: This one definitely would be fast

Comment: @Bharath should be fast I think:-)

Comment: Not as fast as mapping set :) Yours is fastest

Comment: Problem I have with this solution is that it changes the order of value appearence, while the lambda one doesn't

Answer (score 8):

```
In [88]: df.stack().groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: x.unique().tolist())
Out[88]:
0       [1, 2]
1       [2, 3]
2    [5, 4, 9]
dtype: object
```

Comment: Even df.apply(lambda x: list(set(x)), axis = 1) would work

Comment: @Vaishali, yeah, nice! Please turn it into an answer!

Comment: Sir what about my answer ?

Comment: @Vaishali, yes, Wen's solution is extremely elegant!

Answer (score 8):

Lets use `pd.unique` i.e

```
df.T.agg([pd.unique])

        0       1          2
unique  [1, 2]  [2, 3]  [5, 4, 9]
```