# Is there any function to remove duplicate values in rows in jupyter?

Tags: python, csv, jupyter, pandasql

I have a csv file. I need to remove the duplicates values under street_name. ex: I  have multi hwy-1w!
[image]

I used this query: joinedResult.groupby('roadId')['street_name'].apply(', '.join).reset_index().to_csv(f'./2{areaId}.csv', index = False)

Comment: Can you please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so others can reproduce this problem. Screenshots cannot be reproduced and one can't see a thing on this one anyway. 
Assuming you have them in a column of a dataframe you can use `df["street_name"].unique()`. See [pandas docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.unique.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want unique per row, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47439871/get-all-unique-values-in-a-row) might be of help. If you want to keep the data in the row and don't care about order of the string in the row after, maybe this could help:

```py
df['street_name'] = df['street_name'].apply(lambda x: ', '.join(set(x.split(', '))
```

Converting to sets is always a nice way to remove duplicates.

If you need to preserve order, you can use a Counter. It will be slower than using sets though:

```py
from collections import Counter
df['street_name'] = df['street_name'].apply(lambda x: ', '.join(Counter(x.split(', ')).keys()))
```